# displaying multiple tables in a schema of db

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a schema and it consists of n tables . now the thing is to display those multiple tables independently like

Table1

Col1 col2 col3 . . . col n

Table2

Col1 col 2 col3 .....col n
.
.
.

Table N

Col1 col2 col3 ..... Col n

And I have to implement this using pl/sql this is the code I am trying with

```
DECLARE
name varchar2(50);
s_query varchar2(500);
cursor c_demo is select table_name from    user_tables;
BEGIN
open c_demo;
loop
fetch c_demo into name;
EXIT WHEN c_demo%notfound;
select * into s_query from @name; 
dbms_output.put_line(s_query);
end loop;
close c_demo;
end;
```

Comment: You question doesn't make sense.  Can you clarify it?

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL dump ? Or do you want to display the content of your tables using some tabular format ? Or ...

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Printing out all possible values is much harder than you might think.  How do you handle an XMLType, timestamp with timezone, BLOBs, etc?  "Print the whole database" is not a reasonable request, we need more details on what exactly you need to accomplish.

Comment: I have 5 different tables with different columns and I want to select those 5 tables using a single query by using dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MS SQL. If you know the table names try using `UNION`/ `UNION ALL`. If the table definitions doesn't match, use aliases in your `SELECT` query as shown below.

```
SELECT T1COL1 AS COL1,T1COL2 AS COL2,T1COL3 AS COL3 FROM TABLE1 
UNION ALL
SELECT T2COL1 AS COL1,T2COL2 AS COL2,T2COL3 AS COL3 FROM TABLE2
....
SELECT TNCOL1 AS COL1,TNCOL2 AS COL2,TNCOL3 AS COL3 FROM TABLEN
```

Comment: Given the question, good idea, but you need to have a column for the name of the table statically set in each query.  so `SELECT 'Table1' as TableName, col1, col2, col3 from table1` and the columns would need to be of the same datatype and quantity to work, but seems reasonable given question and sample.  You only need to alias the first select in the union however.  All others deffer to the first select.

Comment: Its not union .... I want to the data to be displayed as table1.  Col1 col2 then table 2  col1 col2 like that .... It should look exactly like if we write n select queries for n tables

Comment: Well, that's the best I could understand from your question. Can you try to make your question more clear?

Comment: We can't implement using union because those tables has different number of columns and their data types also different